# Upgrading Terraform (major release upgrade)

Tags: terraform

forgive the daft question but has anyone had any issues with their existing code once they have upgraded to a later version?
I'm running 0.10.6 and want to move to 0.11.2 so I can take advantage of the new functionality missing from my existing version.
I don't fancy breaking my environments by running a later version especially since its a major version change.

Any help is greatly appreciated and received.

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terraform repository contains a [very detailed Changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.11.2/CHANGELOG.md) which describes all fixes, improvements and breaking changes across releases.

A quick glance through deltas `0.10.6` to `0.11.2` shows that the version `0.11.0` release has some things to be aware of, all described in great detail under [0.11.0 Backwards Incompatibilities / Notes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.11.2/CHANGELOG.md#0110-november-16-2017).

As always though, you can simply choose a none production machine to upgrade and then run `terraform plan` until you've ironed out any upgrade issues. Once a plan has been successfully generated you should be *mostly* ok.